# Reset random array item as new variable (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have a random question pulled from an array, with three possible answers pulled from an array within the array. The correct answer is based on the position of the possible answer within the array within the array, and compared to user input in a prompt().

```
ie:[1[correct, x, x], 2[x, correct, x], 3[x, x, correct].
```

For the first random question, the answer number matches the correct answer. After the first question, the answers accepted by the program no longer match the correct answer input by the user. This is the case regardless of the order of the random questions.

eg:

```
Question 2 (displayed first):
1) x 
2) y - correct
3) z

Question 1 (displayed next):
1) a - correct but returns false
2) b - wrong but returns correct
3) c
```

Here is my code. Enter 'quit' to end the prompt box popups.

```js
    var Question = function(question, answerArray, answer) {
      this.question = question;
      this.answerArray = answerArray;
      this.answer = answer;
    };

    Question.prototype.questionPrompt = function() {
      console.log(this.question);
      this.answerArray.forEach(function(answerList, index) {
        console.log(index + ') ' + answerList)
      });
    };

    var questionArray = new Array(
      q1 = new Question('Question A:', ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'A'),
      q2 = new Question('Question B:', ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'B'),
      q3 = new Question('Question C:', ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'C')
    )

    var randomQ = Math.floor(Math.random() * questionArray.length);

    questionArray[randomQ].questionPrompt();

    Question.prototype.answerPrompt = function() {
      var guess = prompt("Enter number of the correct answer.");
      var currentQ = randomQ;
      var tryQ = guess && Number(guess);
      if (currentQ === tryQ) {
        console.log('Correct! ' + this.answer);
        nextQ();
      } else if (guess === "quit") {
    console.log("Goodbye.")
  } else {
        console.log('Try again.' + this.answer);
        nextQ();
      }
    };

    questionArray[randomQ].answerPrompt();

    var newQ;

    function nextQ() {
      newQ = Math.floor(Math.random() * questionArray.length);
      questionArray[newQ].questionPrompt();
      questionArray[newQ].answerPrompt();
    };
```

What is causing the array position of the question inside newQ() to be different from the answer inside newQ(), while the positions for randomQ stay the same?

Comment: It would help a lot if you could make your script runnable show we can walk through each step ourselfs. Look for the `<>` icon in the question editor to create a snippet.

Comment: No idea where `randomQ` comes from.  If the `randomQ` is related to the order of the question on the page, and not in the array, they will not match.  This is a pretty good example of why position based logic should be avoided because it is both confusing, and unnecessarily fragile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue of defining variables in the global scope, and the order in which variables were called. `randomQ` had to be defined inside of an `init()` function to reset the number for the question array, making the newQ variable redundant.

Step 1) Define variables in global scope:

```
var randomQ; 
var guess;
```

Step 2) create `init()` function and move random number code inside it. Call init in global scope:

```
function init(){
  randomQ = Math.floor(Math.random() * questionArray.length);
  questionArray[randomQ].questionPrompt();
  questionArray[randomQ].answerPrompt();
}

init();
```

Step 3) Move prompt to `questionPrompt` from `answerPrompt`, and call `init()` at the end of each if/else statement in `answerPrompt`.

```
// select random question here
  Question.prototype.questionPrompt = function() {
    console.log(this.question);
    this.answerArray.forEach(function(answerList, index) {
      console.log(index + ') ' + answerList)
    });
    guess = prompt("Enter number of the correct answer.");
  };

  // // CHECKS FOR CORRECT ANSWER and prints to console
  Question.prototype.answerPrompt = function() {
    var tryQ = guess && Number(guess);
    if (randomQ === tryQ) {
      console.log('Correct! ' + this.answer);
      init();
    } else if (guess === "quit") {
      console.log("Goodbye.")
    } else {
      console.log('Try again.');
      init();
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Question.prototype.answerPrompt = function() {
  var guess = prompt("Enter number of the correct answer.");
  var currentQ = randomQ;
  var tryQ = guess && Number(guess);
  if (this.answerArray[tryQ + 1] === this.answer) { // answersArray starts at 0
    console.log('Correct! ' + this.answer);
    nextQ();
  } else {
    console.log('Try again.');
    nextQ();
  }
};
```

You are comparing the index of the random question with the index of the selected answer which are not related. You should be checking if the selected answer equals the questions answer.

Comment: Using this code, it no longer seems to recognize the correct answer at all. Sometimes the question and answer will be at the 0 position, so I'm having a hard time understanding adding +1 to tryQ. Would you explain the logic behind that?